# syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'

Tags: c++, c, compilation, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I'm working with OPNET modeler and I inject code to improve my scenario.
when I compile code this message appeared
syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
but it refer to transition that don't have any line of code.

What's the problem?

please, Can anyone help me?

Comment: Look previous code, even, included header files

Comment: No, not without some code. That file must be included somewhere. Check the build log for the last compiled file and post that at least.

Answer (score 11):

That error message indicates that you have a missing semicolon. The most common place this happens is something like the following:

```
class Foo {

    // ...

} // <-- NEED SEMICOLON HERE

int main() {
   // ...
}
```

Note that your `class` declaration may appear in a header file instead of a `.cpp` file.

Comment: I claim credit for pushing you over 200k! Well earned too, if you end up decrypting this question successfully.

Answer (score 6):

This error can also occur for some strict compilers if you declare and assign a variable in the same breath. This can be solved by changing `foo_t my_var = old_var;` and splitting up the statement into

```
foo_t my_var;
my_var = old_var;
```

Ludicrously, some compilers even throw an error if you don't put your variable declarations at the top of the code block.[1]

[1] http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/974f1b6a-7bad-4be7-a93e-66e6b2f18842

Comment: I just got caught by the c declarations thing while building a library (libexif).

Comment: I was working on some OpenCL host code and was stumped by this syntax error - never would've guessed that it was checking for variable declarations only at the top. Thanks for this.